# Add a form to the list output of a view

Tags: views, 8, forms

Assume that I've created a view that outputs a list of cars. For each car, I display the name and the age of the car. This is all done with the Drupal UI. Now I'd like to add a simple button (*Set as favorite*) at the end of each line that when clicked saves the ID of the chosen car in a user's session variable. So my view table should look like the following:

```
Name Age Button
car1 23  'set as favorite'
car2 10  'set as favorite'
```

I am not asking about the session-variable part, but only how I can alter the view output to add a simple button to each row of the list output (I bet it'll be a form in each row).

I've done a lot of reading and I bet this could be done with `hook_views_data_alter` or some other `hook_views_*` but I'm not proceeding. I've already tried drop-buttons as suggested on [Drupal 8 Add custom action buttons to a view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245982/drupal-8-add-custom-action-buttons-to-a-view), but that does not solve the things I need. I need the car's ID I want to save in a session variable, so basically I need a form functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can do this with just a Global custom text field and some hidden view fields.

E.g.:

- Add car id to the view but exclude from view.
- Move this to the top of the list.
- Add a global custom text field for your Favorite button using the replacement values.  Could be something like:

  <a class="btn btn-success" href="/add/favorite/{{ carId }}?destination=/view/cars">Add as Favorite</a>

Notes:

Classes are bootstrap specific.

Href is the code to set the favorite.

Destination string is Drupal way to circle back to view.